# .Net 6 MVC FormCollection value with decimal

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-6.0

I have a checkbox collection with values that contains comma.

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Checkbox Collection</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="1" >
    <label for="check1">Value 1</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="2,3" id="check2">
    <label for="check2">Value 2,3</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="4" id="check3">
    <label for="check3">Value 4</label><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there a way to change the delimiter returned from the form collection.
because the result in the backend if all three are checked

1,2,3,4

And that is wrong, I would like it to say
1;2,3;4
So the collection is separated by semicolon or that I will get three entries back that I can loop thru.

This is a common endpoint with different looking forms being posted to it so we need to loop thru the form.

Backend code in controller is

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult getForm()
{
    Backend.Document doc = null;            
    try
    {
        FormCollection form = (FormCollection)HttpContext.Request.Form;
var cvalues=form["collection"]
```

Comment: show your backend code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way, without changing the delimiter. The name of your checkboxes is `collection`. The model binder of asp.net core can work with that. Pass in a string array parameter with the name collection and the framework will do the rest of the work for you:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Checkbox Collection</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="1" id="check1">
        <label for="check1">Value 1</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="2,3" id="check2">
        <label for="check2">Value 2,3</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="collection" value="4" id="check3">
        <label for="check3">Value 4</label><br>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string[] collection)
{
    foreach (var stringValue in collection)
    {
        //parse to decimal or whatever
        //work with it
    }
    
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Problem is that the html is already generated elsewhere so I can’t change that.

Comment: No need to. The html in my answer is identical to the one in your question - except for the submit button, but that's not a concern for the mechanics of model binding.

Comment: That's correct Marco but sorry I was a bit unclear, I don't know what fields is coming into the post so I need to loop thru the fields on the form. I can't have a fixed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('collection');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
{
  checkboxes[i].name = checkboxes[i].name.replace(/collection/g, 'collection' + i);
}
```

Comment: But I want to achieve this in backend ;-)

Comment: @FredrikNorling Could you please update the C# code in the description ?

Comment: Backend code added